# create entities from yaml file with doctrine in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a symfony doctrine yaml file with the contents:

```
Symchat\SymchatBundle\Entity\Messages:
    type: entity
    table: messages
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        message:
            type: string
            scale: 0
            length: 250
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
        date:
            type: datetime
            scale: 0
            length: null
            unique: false
            nullable: false
            precision: 0
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

But how can i get symfony/doctrine to automatically generate the entity php file?

This seems so simple, but have been going round in circles in the docs trying to find this.

I just want doctrine via symfony to read the yaml file and create the Messages.php entity class.

Comment: `php app/console generate:doctrine:entities Symchat\SymchatBundle`

Comment: :D no way! thank you very much